# Extending jQuery ajax success globally

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to create a global handler that gets called before the ajax success callback.  I do a lot of ajax calls with my app, and if it is an error I return a specific structure, so I need to something to run before success runs to check the response data to see if it contains an error code bit like 1/0

Sample response

```
{"code": "0", "message": "your code is broken"}
```

or

```
{"code": "1", "data": "return some data"}
```

I can't find a way to do this in jQuery out of the box, looked at prefilters, ajaxSetup and other available methods, but they don't quite pull it off, the bets I could come up with is hacking the ajax method itself a little bit:

```
var oFn = $.ajax;

$.ajax = function(options, a, b, c)
{
    if(options.success)
    {
        var oFn2 = options.success;

        options.success = function(response)
        {
            //check the response code and do some processing
            ajaxPostProcess(response);

            //if no error run the success function otherwise don't bother
            if(response.code > 0) oFn2(response);
        }
    }

    oFn(options, a, b, c);
};
```

I've been using this for a while and it works fine, but was wondering if there is a better way to do it, or something I missed in the jQuery docs.

Comment: Sounds like [duck punching](http://paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/)

Comment: Returning an error for a 200 status seems totally wrong. Set the HTTP status to a proper error code (4xx / 5xx) and use the jQuery AJAX `error` handler

Comment: @Phil how about a validation error? returning a 4xx or 5xx seems to be too general.

Comment: @qwertymk I guess that's pretty much what I've done, although I prefer the way they handle the old functions: "return _old.apply(this,arguments);"

Comment: @Rob I +1 your question because your solution is good enough for me

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can build your own AJAX handler instead of using the default ajax:

```
var ns = {};
ns.ajax = function(options,callback){ 
    var defaults = {              //set the defaults
        success: function(data){  //hijack the success handler
            if(check(data)){       //checks
                callback(data);   //if pass, call the callback
            }
        }
    };
    $.extend(options,defaults);  //merge passed options to defaults
    return $.ajax(options);             //send request
}
```

so your call, instead of `$.ajax`, you now use;

```
ns.ajax({options},function(data){
    //do whatever you want with the success data
});
```

Comment: Good answer but there is a problem. Sometimes $.ajax is used by some third party library like Backbone.js so this solution won't work for these cases.

Comment: @WilsonFreitas: Why won't it work for those cases? Does Backbone modify the original $.ajax function? Otherwise I don't see an issue.

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik What the OP wanted was to alter the original AJAX function so that everything that uses it gets the custom config. My solution merely creates a new function with custom config, which the OP can uses in his app globally, but not for other libraries.

Answer (score 5):

This solution transparently adds a custom success handler to every `$.ajax()` call using the [duck punching](http://www.paulirish.com/2010/duck-punching-with-jquery/) technique

```
(function() {
    var _oldAjax = $.ajax;
    $.ajax = function(options) {
        $.extend(options, {
            success: function() {
                // do your stuff
            }
        });
        return _oldAjax(options);
     };
})();
```

Comment: One thing: I had to change it to `options =  $.extend(...)` to make it work. It didn't take `options` by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple suggestions:

```
var MADE_UP_JSON_RESPONSE = {
    code: 1,
    message: 'my company still uses IE6'
};

function ajaxHandler(resp) {
    if (resp.code == 0) ajaxSuccess(resp);
    if (resp.code == 1) ajaxFail(resp);
}

function ajaxSuccess(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

function ajaxFail(data) {
    alert('fml...' + data.message);
}

$(function() {

    // 
    // setup with ajaxSuccess() and call ajax as usual
    //
    $(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
        ajaxHandler(MADE_UP_JSON_RESPONSE);
    });

    $.post('/echo/json/');

    // ----------------------------------------------------
    //             or
    // ----------------------------------------------------

    // 
    // declare the handler right in your ajax call
    //
    $.post('/echo/json/', function() {
        ajaxHandler(MADE_UP_JSON_RESPONSE);
    });
});​
```

Working: http://jsfiddle.net/pF5cb/3/

Comment: hmm, ya, the issue though is that i have like 100 ajax calls each with "success" code that runs if the response returns a good code.  I would have to go to each success function and wrap this code around.  I prefer to just have clean code in the success functions and not have the dev team worry about wrapping these guys, should just work, at least that's my goal.

Comment: The `ajaxHandler` function I gave is global.  You only need to declare it once if you use the `ajaxSuccess()` option.

Comment: Yes, but my success functions are not all the same, many of them do different things on a successful ajax request.

Comment: @Rob: have you considered using the `complete` function ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the most basic example:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    success: function(data){  
        //default code here
    }
});
```

Feel free to look up [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/) on `$.ajaxSetup()`

Comment: It says: "Set default values for future Ajax requests. **Its use is not recommended.**"

Answer (score 0):

this is your call to ajax method

```
 function getData(newUrl, newData, callBack) {
           $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               url: newUrl,
               data: newData,
               dataType: "json",

               ajaxSuccess: function () { alert('ajaxSuccess'); },
               success: function (response) {
                   callBack(true, response);
                   if (callBack == null || callBack == undefined) {
                       callBack(false, null);
                   }
               },
               error: function () {
                   callBack(false, null);
               }
           });
       }
```

and after that callback success or method success

```
$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
               alert('ajax ajaxStart called');
           });
           $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
               alert('ajax gvPerson ajaxSuccess called');
           });
```

Comment: $(document).ajaxSuccess(function () {
               alert('ajax gvPerson ajaxSuccess called');
           });